The usage of the past perfect in past tense books
I've chosen these examples from a book written in the past tense where one character remembers something:

They'd fought well but were heavily outnumbered.

(In my opinion, the sentence should be: They'd fought well but had been heavily outnumbered.)

He'd observed the noblemen of the Gauri court as their gazes followed Ildiko during the wedding ceremony.

(In my opinion, the sentence should be: He'd observed the noblemen of the Gauri court as their gazes had followed Ildiko during the wedding ceremony.)
I also notice that in many past tense books, authors started a paragraph relating to the old days with the past perfect but suddenly switched to the past tense even though still remembering those old days.
Can you please explain why?

Why would they not? By the time they switch, everybody knows what happened when so there's no reason to work so hard. We get this question all the time. I hope someone can find a good canonical answer.

The job of past perfect is to set that verb further in the past than one in the past simple. So it's confusing to use the perfect twice in a sentence.

All these examples are relatively informal, using 'd. You can't expect such writing to follow the simple rules you learn in ESL/EFL class. (Btw I think this belongs on English Language Learners. It's certainly a duplicate there.)

It wouldn't be wrong to repeat the past perfect tense, but it's unnecessary because the first use establishes that the incident described is set back in time.
